# Wrong IP address (Different from the setting in LAN Port)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

The LAN port of my router is set to 192.168.1.1, but my device sometimes gets an IP address of 192.168.31.xxx, and it cannot connect to the Internet.

I need to forget this network to reconnect and get the IP address of 192.168.1.xxx to get online, but it will become 192.168.31.xxx again for a while, and I need to reconnect again.

why is that?

Comment: You might have a “rogue” DHCP server, i.e. some other device in your network that serves IP addresses but that’s configured for a different address range. You’ll have to look hard at every router or other “smart” device that connects to your network, to make sure they don’t have some kind of DHCP server enabled. Another possibility could be that the device configures itself in the 192.168.31.x range when no DHCP server responds within a certain timeout period.

Comment: Depending on what kind of device gets the wrong IP address, you might be able to look up where (what server) it got its “192.168.31.x” address from.